# Is it possible to trigger a function if somebody visits a webpage?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to write a Google Apps script and check if my website is visited or not by anybody. Is there a Analytics class method to trigger a function such as sending Email? I don't want to set a installable trigger which runs function below in each minute. It seems to me a very crude way.

```
function getVisitors(){
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    "ga:742****",
    "2019-12-01",
    "2019-12-16",
    'ga:users,ga:sessions,ga:pageviews',
    {'dimensions': 'ga:date'});
  Logger.log(results);
}
```

Comment: What is a page?

Comment: To clarify, would you send an email to yourself (i.e. admin of the site) or the visitor?

Comment: @Cooper a webpage of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and post from your owned web page to your Google web app. Your Google web app can then trigger ga analytics function.